# Transparent Activity, with a faint tint of Grey

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, transparent

I am trying to have a transparent Activity, with a faint grey Color tint, over another activity. I am able to invoke the transparent activity, but I am not able to get the Greyish Tint. Please help me. Following is my code.

```
    <style name="Theme.Transparent">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/transparent_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
<drawable name="transparent_background">#FFFECA11</drawable>
```

No matter what colour value I provide for the drawable, it is not being reflected as the background. The definition in manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayHelpActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_help" 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Can you please let me know wat is missing?
P.S. Please forget the color value. Its just random I used to test if it works.

I used the following as well

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
```

instead of the drawable, and in my color.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
       <color name="transparent">#80ffeeca</color>
    </resources>
```

it still has no effect. Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to put activities on top of each other. If you want to show something on top of your normal activity, then using a [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) is a posible solution:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:id="@+id/underlying_layout" >

        <!--Put the parts of your normal activity here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#88666666"
        android:id="@+id/top_layout">

        <!--Put the parts of the layout here, 
        what should be on top of your activity-->

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Now if you want to make the top level stuff appear or disappear, then you can use the Views [`setVisibility()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) function like this:

```
View topLevelLayout = findViewById(R.id.top_layout);

//make it disappear with all its sub-Views
topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

//make it appear with all its sub-Views
topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

### UPDATE

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I never knew this. But I want the top level layout to be transparent. i.e. I wanna see them both. its more of a extra info in the top layout, which fits with the views in bottom layout. Like help.

Comment: By the way, am using Scrollview and Relative Layout. Will the frame layout fit as parent to both of them, or should it be a child to scroll view?

Comment: I got the answer! :). I made the backgroundDimEnabled true. it worked. Thanks for your help :).

        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true.</item>
        
Am yet to test the colour though. To see if the colour makes any changes to the dim.

Comment: Let me show you in some pictures what happens, se my updated answer!

Comment: wow. thank you for taking some time to explain me :). Thats something new I learned which I can definitely use. By the way, that top layout. can I make that transparent?

Comment: Of course :) by giving it a transparent background color(like #88cccccc, this is half transparent, gray), or a transparent background drawable (PNG)

Comment: thanks. that's new :). But, if possible, please let me know, why this way of specifying a background color to an activity not working in my case. wud be helpful to know more :).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem lies within the value of the color itself.

```
#FFFECA11
```

The reason being that the color is broken down into four values, #AARRGGBB. The first two are the transparent values, and by using **FF** in your first two values, you are ensuring that it is not transparent. Try using the following value to get around 50% transparency:

```
#7FFECA11
```

For more information, see the following link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

Comment: Am sry, but I dint get any change. That is one problem am facing now. That is my question. No matter wat value I provide, it is not being reflected.

Comment: Is the layout being using by this activity possibly overwriting this theme based on the android:background value?

Comment: The transparent activity is a relative layout and nothing regarding the theme is defined there. I hope I answered correctly, cuz I did not understand your question completely

Comment: I got the answer! :). I made the backgroundDimEnabled true. it worked. Thanks for your help :).

        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true.</item>
        
Am yet to test the colour though. To see if the colour makes any changes to the dim.

Comment: Glad to help! Hopefully the color also works as expected / described by the reference documents.

Comment: No. :(. The color is not working. Am able to dim it. exactly like the grey I want. But the color seems to have no effect :(. I will be really glad if you can help me with why it isn't.