# how to pop a dialog but still being able to control background activity

Tags: android, android-layout

i am currently trying to just pop up a picture while a certain activity, for instance an alarm clock just set off. 
while that alarm clock is running i would like to pop a picture over the alarm clock regular clock picture but still  enable the user to switch the alarm clock off.
so far i have only been able to pop a transparent activity which wont let u touch anything in background.
                                                                                           would like to have the picture just appear for a few seconds and then disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I think this method may help. Try to pop up another activity, and have your pop up picture as image view in that activity. And since you want to switch off the alarm as well, maybe you can have a button in the activity shown, that can control the alarm as well. You can make a activity transparent and pop up by editing styles. Answers for those are here

[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Comment: i want to control the true alarm button. not to make my own in the new activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230686/transparent-activity-with-a-faint-tint-of-grey

look at the answer with the vote. I think using frame layout, you can make one of your layouts floating like a popup, and still be in the same activity and control your alarm.

you can control its visibility as well, thus you can make it disappear after some time.